# Issue while using filtering or masking in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, filtering, masking

Here is my jupyter code:-

```
boxes1 = tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
boxes2=np.random.randn(19, 19, 5, 4)
```

and here I have found value of `filtering_mask` variable

```
box_confidence=np.random.randn(19, 19, 5, 1)
box_class_probs=np.random.randn(19, 19, 5, 80)
box_scores = box_confidence * box_class_probs  
box_class_scores = tf.reduce_max(box_scores, axis=-1)
filtering_mask = box_class_scores>= .5
```

finally when we see shape

```
boxes1.shape, boxes2.shape , filtering_mask.shape
```

we get

```
(TensorShape([19, 19, 5, 4]), (19, 19, 5, 4), TensorShape([19, 19, 5]))
```

and now doing masking

```
boxes1[filtering_mask]
```

this works, but

```
boxes2[filtering_mask]
```

this doesn't

Can anyone tell me the reason, as for same kind of setting for some other pair(where `boxes1` being tensor and `boxes2` being numpy array) filtering works, but in this case it is not working and giving me error as:-

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 4-dimensional, but 38 were indexed
```

note: I have written full code to calculate value of each variable so you can run it on your system to confirm the error.
here is the screenshot of error:-
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1xGn.png)

Here is another case where I am not having issue because of different kind of objects numpy and tensor:-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(10)
box_confidence = tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 1], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
boxes = tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
box_class_probs = tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 80], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1) box_scores = box_confidence * box_class_probs   
box_classes = tf.math.argmax(box_scores, axis=-1)  
box_class_scores = tf.reduce_max(box_scores, axis=-1) 
boxes1 = box_class_scores

filtering_mask = box_class_scores>= .5
```

`boxes1[filtering_mask]`  # works

Now we convert to numpy array and it still works in this situation

```
boxes2= np.array(box_class_scores)
boxes2[filtering_mask]  
box_class_scores.shape    
here shape is (19,19,5) of boxes1 and boxes2. same shape like filtering_mask (19,19,5)
```

**To sum up** , what I observed is when applying `A[B]` if both shape of A and B are same then we can have A either as tensor or numpy array but if shape are not same Like in first case when A was `(19,19,5,4)` and B `(19,19,5)` then A can only be a tensor (given B is a tensor), please tell me if this is wrong and any reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your question. You have written `boxes1[filtering_mask]` will get an error, but as your screenshot specified, `boxes2[filtering_mask]` gets error.

Anyway, `boxes1` is a tensor and `boxes2` is numpy array and you can see the difference between them in the line where you get their shape output.

The warning in your screenshot tells everything.
You Just need to convert `boxes2` to a tensor like this:

```
boxes2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(boxes2)
boxes2[filtering_mask]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this but in some other scenario this is not causing problem, I have updated the question please look into it.

Comment: Are you sure that in your second scenario ``boxes2[filtering_mask]`` works? Test it again.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is not showing error, you can confirm by executing  it on your computer also.